# Cancel event on change of option from dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have below code where I am taking confirmation on change of select from the dropdown. If the user selects any option from the list and then click on cancel, I want to change the option to default "select any one" on cancel event of the confirmation alert. Currently what gets selected is chosen as default.

```
$scope.GetValue = function(newObj, oldObj) {
var dialog = confirm('Continue?');
if (dialog) {
  alert("Changing from "+oldObj+"to "+newObj);
}
else {
$scope.valueProps = '';
}
```

}

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vn0q5jwh/1/)

Any help on how to change the option to default (select any one) if cancel event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use an object key as select option value when you using same object in parent loop.

First in first, use another scope instead of loop object for options

```
$scope.optionList = [
  "For any event on all my projects",
  "For any event on the selected projects only...",
  "Only for things I watch or I'm involved in",
  "Only for things I am assigned to",
  "Only for things I am the owner of",
  "No events"
];
```

And you may not want to use a scope for loop item selection. 
`$scope.valueProps = '';`
You can store old value in loop item as key like oldValue

```
{
    "key": "all",
    "value": "",
    "oldValue": ""
  },
```

And change event pass loop item as parameter to your function

```
function GetValue(row) {
  if (confirm('Continue?')) {
    alert('Changing from ' + row.oldValue + 'to ' + row.value);
    // You should change your old value with new value after alert notify
    row.oldValue = row.value;
  } else {
    // if confirm rejects then change value with old value
    row.value = row.oldValue;
  }
}
```

I made some changes in your code, Please check it out;

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/68ro3ujv/1/)

Comment: @KevinO Ah yes. I added code in to the answser. Thank you for warning me. :)